# nock call to fs.readFileSync(file)

Tags: node.js, nock

I have a function where I am reading the contents of a file and then doing some processing as:

```
public static process(filepath: string): string {
    let fileContent = fs.readFileSync(filepath);

    // some processing with filecontent
    // ..
    //..
}
```

I am writing unit tests for it. for one of the tests, I would like to nock the call fs.readFileSync(filepath) to return some content I would like to set. Is there a way to nock call to fs.readFileSync(filepath) ?

I started with creating a sinon.stub as:

```
sinon.stub(fs, 'readFileSync');
```

But, it returns me an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'sections' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `'readFilesync("test.css")'` is not a valid method name.

```
var readFileSyncMock = function(fileName) {
    var mockFileContents = "blah blah blah"; // This can be anything
    return mockFileContents;
};

sinon.stub(fs, 'readFileSync', readFileSyncMock);
```

Comment: Aaron, Can you elaborate on how you are creating readFileSyncMock?

Comment: readFileSyncMock is just a function that you define.  It can be anything.  In the case of this test you would want it to return whatever data the "test.css" file would normally return.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but I get this error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token b in JSON at position 0  (I think its complaining on the characters of the text we are returning

Comment: of course. I don't know the context of the processing.  You have to write the mock function to return what you expect

Comment: No, I just have this code you provided in the test right now. I have not yet called the actual method to be tested. Just putting this code is giving that error

Comment: There is no json parsing happening anywhere in the code that I provided.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156967/discussion-between-aaron-roberts-and-user1892775).

Comment: I joined the chat and messaged you there